# Retrieve data from Controller to View using Json to HighCharts

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, highcharts

I trying to use HighCharts on my MVC project. I followed this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1f3f2a/charting-in-mvc/
it works, but they use PIE CHART and I need BAR or LINE CHART.

On My CONTROLLER:

```
ContasReceberData recData = new ContasReceberData();
List<IndiceInadimplencia> indices = new List<IndiceInadimplencia>();

indices = recData.GetIndices(data1, data2, empresa)
      .Select(o => new IndiceInadimplencia
      {
          MesIndice = o.Mes,
          Indice = Math.Round(o.Inad_Atual / o.Receitas * 100, 2)
      }).ToList();        

return Json(indices, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Json Return: 
indice: 20
month: "JAN"

On View:

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Painel/Indices',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            delay: 15,            
            success: function (data) {

                var series = new Array();                

                for (var i in data) {  
                    var serie = new Array(data[i].MesIndice, data[i].Indice);                   
                    series.push(serie);                                    
                }

                indicesInadimplencia(series);

            },

            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });      
    });
```

That funcition will return: ["JAN", 20], ["FEV", 25]...

and HighCharts need:
Categories: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR"]
Serie: [20,25,22]

How can I change ["JAN", 20] to:

array month = ["JAN", "FEV"]
array indice = [20,25]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the `data` and populate two seperate arrays one with `Categories` and one with `Series` :

```
var Categories = new Array();
var Series = new Array();
for (var i=0; i < data.Length; i++) 
{                    
     Categories.push(data[i].MesIndice);    
     Series.push(data[i].Indice);                                
}
```

Comment: I dont know why, but Series array came empty: http://prntscr.com/9s8j8h. How can I see array content on JavaScript? Here the model list on CONTROLLER: http://prntscr.com/9s73jk

Answer (score 0):

Worked!!!

I tried like:

```
var Categories = new Array();
var Series = new Array();

for (var i in data) { 

Categories.push(data[i].MesIndice);
Series.push(data[i].Indice);

}
```

Thank you!!! Ehsan Sajjad